# How to send whatsapp messages without saving number?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Please let me know, without using any third party application, how to send whatsapp message without saving a number in contact?

Regards
Smith

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do the following trick

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=xxxxxx

Copy this and paste it on your browser, please replace "xxxxxx" with the phone number (with country code but without +. **Example= https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=901234567890**), then hit enter. This will redirect you to WhatsApp and you will begin to talk to contact without saving the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, download [SharkID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sharkid) app and login.

From their Dialer Screen, type your numner and Swipe Left. You will see the 'WhatsApp' button, click on it. If WhatsApp is installed then, it goes directly to that number.